# Flask_app second Webapp overwritten

Tags: pythonanywhere

Today I tried to start a new web app. But while making a second web app, I did not notice that the sourcecode directory was the same as my first web app. Consequently, my first web-app-sourcecode was overwritten by a standard boilerplate flask_app template.

I did retrieve the flask_app-cpython-36.pyc, but tryng to decompile it using uncompyle6, I keep on getting the error
`ImportError: Ill-formed bytecode file flask_app.cpython-36.pyc <class 'TypeError'> File flask_app.cpython-36.pyc doesn't smell like Python bytecode: expecting code indicator 'c'; got ''`

Is there a way to go back to the previous version of the flask_app?

Comment: How are you running Flask app? Using `flask run` command after setting env var?

Comment: It is a pythonanywhere flask app. ``# import flask app but need to call it "application" for WSGI to work
from flask_app import app as application  # noqa``

Comment: Makes sense. So the original src code you got was `pyc` file, not `py`, right?

Comment: Neh, it was a Py but when it compiles it back ups the pyc file as it is faster to work with. The kind people at pythonanywhere already started the recovery process from there backups, but still I wonder why I can't get the pyc to decompile

Comment: If you contact support@pythonanywhere.com someone can check if it's possible to recover your old files from backup. Anyways, it makes sense to keep your code in version control (eg. git)